# Laravel + Carbon + SQL time formatting problem

Tags: mysql, datetime, php-carbon

Can someone please assist me with the following problem. I am using Carbon to get the current time. Once I got the time and send it to my (myphpadmin) database it displays the whole date and time and not just the time. Here are all the code being used.

Laravel Code:

```
            $date = Carbon::parse(now())->timezone('GMT+2');
            $time = $date->toTimeString();
            $UserRequest->finished_at = $time;
```

SQL Database layout and format:

[image]

Display: (Incorrect)

[image]

I have literally tried all the custom formatting from Carbon docs nothing sends over just the time.

I need this format -> 12:09 pm

Table Structure:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I am using xammp with phpmyadmin (InnoDB)

Comment: `$time = $date->format('g:i A');`   reference here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 0):

The problem more complicated than you describe.
First looks as `finished_at` is datetime field, so you can not store only date in this field. Sure, you can change the column format to time and store only time part. But this approach can cause problem with overdate date (started_at may be previous day or early).

So I think you need not change your storing flow, but you can change representation flow by using appropriate format

Comment: The finished_at column is using varchar

Comment: It's even worst than datetime. Please use right data formats. Please update your question with table structure.

Comment: Please see the updated table structure. Thanks